# Communicate two views with one controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, communication

I'm using UI-Router for Angular and I have separated views for my app: sidebar and main. Now i need to change some class in main view after some action that does in sidebar view.

So, this is my code:

**config**

```
.state('app.area', {
    url: '/area/:areaId',
    views: {
        '@': {
            template: require('./app/generic/genericWithSidebar.html'),
            controller: 'AreaCtrl'
        },
        'main@app.area': {
            template: require('./app/area/_area.html'),
            controller: 'AreaCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'CTRL',
        },
        'sidebar@app.area': {
            template: require('./app/area/_sidebar.html'),
            controller: 'AreaCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'CTRL',
        }
    },
```

**controller**

```
class AreaCtrl {
    constructor($scope) {
        "ngInject";

        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$scope.descriptionIsActive = false;
    }

    showAreaDescription() {
        this.$scope.descriptionIsActive = !this.$scope.descriptionIsActive;
    }
}

export default AreaCtrl;
```

**and views for sidebar and main**

```
// sidebar view
<span ng-click="CTRL.showAreaDescription()">show more</span>
// main view
<div ng-class="{'active': CTRL.descriptionIsActive}"></div>
```

I need to communicate between views, not controllers, i have one controller.

Comment: Need to be aware that each view initializes a new instance of `AreaCtrl` each with it's own scope

Comment: @charlietfl So, what should i do? Should i remove controller definition for view and leave only for parent?

Comment: probably .....yes. Not really enough known about the app though

Comment: You can use $broadcast for that ype of situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs: using service to communicate between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482488/angularjs-using-service-to-communicate-between-controllers)

Comment: @driconmax how could i find that? not fair!

Comment: I just used Google. "communicate between controllers"

Comment: dude, this is not communication between controllers - between views! quite different thing

Comment: ......? Really man? Did you at least read the post?

Comment: The answer you marked as correct is just the same as the duplicate question.

Comment: OK, fine, but how could I find that what i was looking for having in mind what need, which is communication between views. As you can see, google is not searching that, also there was any hint while i wasn't typing my question. Now there is other question with the almost same problem. What should i do right now, remove my question? Or maybe the answers bellow are valuable? And in my opinion this is not fair to down voting just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" solution depends on what it is that changed in your main view that causes a change in the navigation.

As I just [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42134294/2319378), it is generally a bad sign if you need controllers to "talk" to each other. This often means that you should have a `service` that takes care of the data/state that you want to bind to in both views.

If, however, your change is really just a global cosmetic navigational thing (I can not think of an example but I do not want to say that thats impossible), a "global" `NavigaitonController` (on your `body` for example) might be correct. I doubt it though.

So my suggestion is: Think about what data causes the change, handle the state of that data in its own service and bind to that service property where you need it.

Comment: So, this ok that i've used one, other controller for action in sidebar? In that case everything is working fine. Thx from the top for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your controller outside the `views` option so that it will only load once on state load.

```
stateProvider.state("app.area",{
   url:'/app.area',
   templateUrl: 'app_area_frame.html',
   controller:'AreaCtrl',
   controllerAs: 'CTRL',
   views:{
      'main':{
          template: require('./app/area/_area.html')
      },
      'sidebar':{
          template: require('./app/area/_sidebar.html')
      }
   }

})
```

Nested views for `UI-router` [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)

Comment: No, i don't have access to controller in views :(

Comment: How do you mean? :)

Comment: Simple, the actions form controller is not propagating, what i use it in main view it's working correctly...

Comment: @Lukas he is suggesting you to use a single Controller to all the Views. Witch is not correct.... but it could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

State is meant to be encapsulated by services, so in fact, if you have state that should be shared across the app, you should create a service.

Alternatively, you can have a controller in a higher scope, say you have a controller for the app, which can then be inherited by the sidebar and main page child scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is not the exact answer for your particular question. But from a architecture's view you should not use nested views to handle main view with sidebar.

Because this sidebar should be same for all states. So if you are using nested views you should specify your sidebar each time. Also you should write the code for sidebar in every states. That is not a recommended way to design your application.

I strongly recommend you to go through this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065150/1979465).

**Then how to design?**

Make your sidebar as a simple template and use ng-include to render your footer part.

```
<footer ng-include="'/sidebar.html'" ng-controller="sidebarController"></footer>
```

As you can see there is a dedicated controller for your sidebar and you don't need to duplicate your code to each main controller.

Comment: Nope, sidebar will be different for different pages, so i need to have separated child views for it and main section.

Comment: @Lukas okay, if the case is like that then use nested views.